# Get selectedvalue from combobox in DataGridTemplateEditColumn c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox

I bind a DataGrid from codebehind with this method:

```
private void BindDataGridSetup()
        {
            //Do datefiltereing first to get left join to work
            var datefiltered = data.View_NAV_Entries.Where(e => e.DATO >= this.StartDate && e.DATO <= this.EndDate);

            //Linq to get data for "Setup" grid.
            var querySetup = from m in data.R_Masterdata
                             join a in data.View_R_GetAccounts on m.SubsidiaryId equals a.S_Dataset into setup
                             from accplan in setup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join config in data.R_Configuration on new { MasterDataId = m.MasterDataId, Account = accplan.No_ }
                             equals new { config.MasterDataId, config.Account } into conf
                             from x in conf.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join component in data.R_Component on new { ComponentId = x.ComponentId, MasterDataId = x.MasterDataId }
                             equals new { component.ComponentId, this.MasterDataId } into comp
                             from com in comp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join e in datefiltered
                             on new { DATASET = accplan.S_Dataset, KONTO = accplan.No_ }
                             equals new { e.DATASET, e.KONTO } into entries
                             from ent in entries.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             where
                              m.SubsidiaryId.Equals(this.SubsidiaryId)
                              && accplan.S_Dataset.Equals(this.SubsidiaryId)
                             group ent by new { accplan.No_, accplan.Name, x.Eliminate, com.ComponentId, com.ComponentName } into grp
                             orderby grp.Key.No_

                             select new
                             {
                                 AccNumber = grp.Key.No_,
                                 AccName = grp.Key.Name,
                                 Saldo = grp.Sum(e => (e.BELOBDKK == null ? 0 : e.BELOBDKK)),
                                 Component = grp.Key.ComponentName == null ? "Vælg komponent" : grp.Key.ComponentName,
                                 ComponentId = grp.Key.ComponentId == null ? 0 : grp.Key.ComponentId,
                                 Components = data.R_Component.ToList().Where(x => !x.ComponentName.Contains("Blank")),
                                 ConfEliminate = grp.Key.Eliminate
                             };


            try
            {
                DataGridSetup.ItemsSource = querySetup.ToList();



            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(e.InnerException.ToString());
            }
        }
```

And I am binding with this XAML:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Component" Header="Komponent">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{ Binding Component }"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxSetup"   Height="16"  
                                      ItemsSource="{ Binding  Components }"
                                      DisplayMemberPath="ComponentName"
                                      SelectedValuePath="{ Binding ComponentId }">
                                <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="19"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The textbox shows fine and when I double-click on the ComboBox it drops down with the possibilities. All fine.
But I can't get hold on the SelectedValue from the ComboBox from code behind.

How do I get the Selected value from the ComboBox?

Comment: You could bind the `ComboBox` `SelectedValue` to a property in the (code-behind) and then pick it up from `SelectionChanged` event handler. I assume that this is a `UserControl` that's why you are using code-behind? Otherwise look into [MvvM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial).

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right that the Model View Viewmodel is the way to proceed.